# remove date from DateTimePicker for Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446530.aspx

but there is no possibility to null date or to delete date from text field.

how to remove date from textfield or how to connect TextField with DateTimePicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display blank you can set it as

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "";
```

and then reset the format in `ValueChanged` event to the desired format. The picker doesn't allow null values since it requires a valid DateTime object.

You may choose to have a custom control also as [found here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/CFDateTimePicker.aspx)

Comment: thx you. I will choose this custom control. What if i want delete date from design? Delete button not working, i can not delete any text in  DateTimePicker

Comment: i've done this in the past and works fine, i just used a different customformat where i would replace the date inputs by underscores, so dd-MM-yyyy would show up as __-__-____