# Custom Date format in Masked Text Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, maskedtextbox

Iam using `Masked Text box` for inputing a Date.
But I want to set `custom date format` for this text box. 
How can I set `custom date format and validate date on masked text box` control

Comment: why dont you use a Datetimepicker?

Comment: Current date automatically comes there in the datetime picker. I want to allow the user to enter so that they can remind about that.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should use a `DateTime` Picker for getting such inputs (i think you want it to avoid the mouse probably)

least you can set a mask like `00/00/0000` and later on subscribe for the `Validating` event of the maskedtextbox and use `Parse` or `ParseExact` to verfiy the `Date` entered.

In case you want to have blank for date picker then check out this solution [remove date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554234/570150)